# CallBack in React Native

Tags: react-native

I tried to build a sample app for callback functionality between native module and JavaScript Module in react Native app.

But it says the class CallBack canoot be found.I tried to use the following code for communication between native module and javascript :-

MyNativeClass.java

```
  import com.facebook.react.bridge.CallBack;


  @ReactMethod
  public void getText(CallBack callback){
  callback.invoke('Hi From Java');
 }
```

MyJavaScript.js

```
 export default class App extends Component<{}> {
   NativeModule.getText(status) => {
      console.log('Result',status);
    }
   render() {
      return (
      <Text>
       From Java  { this.getText() }
       </Text>
      }});
  }
```

The Java module is also packed and is exposed

```
  import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
  module.exports =  NativeModules.MyNativeClass;
```

I tried clean and built as well but still i am facing the same issue cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.CallBack.

**Update** :I did the same on fresh project as well but same error on importing CallBack library.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle. There should be a line:

```
dependencies {
 ...
 compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" //or a version
 ...
}
```

I do suggest you start with a new project, to retry. The error does seems that the library is not being included.

Comment: Thanks but same error not only CallBack but many modules inside bridge package have this issue.Is it moved or package is renamed any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just thinking there might be 2 problems:
1) Either the project opened in android studio is not under <your project>/android folder
2) build.gradle within the project, does not contain maven{url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"}

Comment: would you check if these are there?